# How to partial refresh a include php page?

Tags: php, partial-page-refresh

```
<?php include("news.php"); ?>
```

Hello, I include a `news.php` in my main page `index.php`. I want to refresh the `news.php` every 30 seconds, but not refresh the main page `index.php`, How to partial refresh a include php page? Thanks.

Comment: That will need Javascript. Are you using any at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for something similar and it's taken a while but I think this might work:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
    $("#screen").load('news.php')
    }, 2000);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to refresh an include (Valid only if the include only contains variables and their values):

```
<?php
$config = file_get_contents("news.php");
$config = str_replace("<?php", "", $config);
$config = str_replace("?>", "", $config);
eval($config);
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

Very easy method to refresh include (only for backend single user, not for frontend):

```
<?php
$t = time();
rename("news.php", "news_${t}.php");
include("news_${t}.php");
rename("news_${t}.php", "news.php");
?>
```